Visualizing log events on AWS CloudWatch Dashboard, programmatically declaring using CDK
I would like to create (programmatically) dashboard and alerts for component I write. So far, when I needed dashboard to display information based on application logs, I used Sumologic which is quite feature rich for this purpose.
Trying to achieve same thing in AWS CloudWatch, I'm struggling to:

1. Display (stacked) bar chart for events by time frame (stats)
Considering I have log event like this:
{
  "_t": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "_l": "Error",
  "_mt": "Something went brrr"
}

There are log events with _l = Critical, Error, Warning ...
I would like to calculate number of errors per time frame, e.g. by 15 minutes: stats count(_l) as c by bin(15m), _l
When I try to display this with cloudwatch.GraphWidgetView.BAR, I would like to see many bars, each for 15 minute time frame. Actual result is that I get single bar spanning whole graph duration, aggregating all counts together.
const criticalErrorMetricFilter = new logs.MetricFilter(this, 'CriticalErrorMetricFilter', 
{
  // ...
  metricValue: "1",
  filterPattern: logs.FilterPattern.all(
    logs.FilterPattern.any(
      logs.FilterPattern.stringValue("$._l", "=", "Critical"),
      logs.FilterPattern.stringValue("$._l", "=", "Error"),
    ),
    logs.FilterPattern.stringValue("$._t", "!=", "test"),
  ),
  unit: cloudwatch.Unit.COUNT,
});

const criticalErrorMetric = criticalErrorMetricFilter.metric({
  statistic: cloudwatch.Stats.SUM,
  label: "Critical Errors",
});

new cloudwatch.GraphWidget({
  title: 'Critical Errors',
  left: [
    criticalErrorMetricFilter.metric({
      statistic: cloudwatch.Stats.SUM,
      label: "Critical Errors",
    }),
  ],
  view: cloudwatch.GraphWidgetView.BAR,
  width: 24,
  height: 6,
})

Actual:
                
 │              
 │              
 │              
 │ ┌─────────┐  
 │ │         │  
 └─┴─────────┴─ 
                

Desired:
                
 │              
 │              
 │ ┌─┐          
 │ │ │     ┌─┐  
 │ │ │     │ │  
 └─┴─┴─────┴─┴─ 
                

Additionally regarding stacking: there are several message types with different _l, e.g. Error and Warning and I would like to stack those values on top of each other in single graph. Is that even possible?

2. Display line graph, if there are no data, use value 0
For other type of graph, using stats, I would like to treat missing values as 0. When I apply filter, certainly I'm adding gaps in my data.
I tried declaring field (_l = "Error" and ...) as is_critical_error without specifying any filter, but when it doesn't match, instead of 0 value is still empty.
filter _l = "Error" // <- omit to get *all* entries
| stats count(_l) as c by bin(15m) as t, _l




time
_l
c




00:00
Error
0


00:15
Error
2


00:30
Error
3


00:45
Error
0


...




01:15
Error
2



(I don't know how to create rows with c = 0)
Actual:
Lines are broken, there are gaps. Sometimes, there's just dot if stats doesn't return adjacent time frames.
                
 │              
 │              
 │   x          
 │  x       x   
 │           x  
 └───────────── 
                

Desired:
                
 │              
 │              
 │   x          
 │  x       x   
 │           x  
 │xx──xxxxxx─── 
                

3. Display line graph with dynamic number of dimensions
Another view of data is line graph depicting N values by time. Here are theoretical data (again after applying stats and grouping)



t
svc
c




00:00
foo
13


00:00
bar
2


00:00
baz
6


00:15
bar
42



I'm not able to visualize those data using line graph, but I would expect something like:
Desired:
                
 │              
 │     yyy      
 │ x  y   y     
 │x xy   x y  x 
 │  yx  x x yx  
 │yy──xx───xxyy 
                

(bear with me, X is one line (e.g. "foo"), Y is other line (e.g. "bar")
Including also handling missing values for given time slot.
So far I was playing with query, not even tried to put this to CDK code. Is this possible with CloudWatch?
